# What can be the causes of this logcat? What do I check for?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api

Recently Android 9 and 10 devices have reported this crash in the Google play reports.
I am not able to understand what can be the cause of this crash, I have tried several devices, Samsung remote test labs, but I could not reproduce this crash and nearly all models I tried worked fine.
However, the crash reports have increased reaching thousands now. And the crash only happens on Android 9,10 devices.
Can someone please guide me on what to look for, or the possible issues that could be the cause of the crash?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2096)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2056)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2004)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiver (IActivityManager.java:5595)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal (ContextImpl.java:1589)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1550)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1538)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver (ContextWrapper.java:641)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zaa (GoogleApiAvailability.java:64)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zab (zaaw.java:311)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaf.onConnectionSuspended (zaaf.java:42)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.onConnectionSuspended (zabe.java:106)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zap.onConnectionSuspended (zap.java:9)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnectionSuspended (zaf.java:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.handleMessage (BaseGmsClient.java:40)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi.dispatchMessage (zzi.java:8)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8016)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiver (ActivityManagerService.java:17096)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact (IActivityManager.java:2269)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact (ActivityManagerService.java:3376)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1021)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:994)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks you are trying to `registerReceiver` with `Fragment` that is not yet attached to any `Activity`. Can you please check you have `registerReceiver` in appropriate lifecycle.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the case. I don't have this functionality in my code anywhere!